# Google Drive API webContentLink redirects to a different domain

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am using the Google Drive API to access files on my team drive.  My server application uses OAuth2 to obtain an access token.  I then use this token as a Bearer token to make API drive calls.  When I am trying to download an image from my team drive, one of the files listed when calling the https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files endpoint is:

`{
  "id": "<longAlphaNumericID>",
  "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
  "webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/a/<myTeamDriveDomain>/uc?id=SOME_GOOGLE_DRIVE_ID&export=download",
  "fileExtension": "jpg",
  "size": "108794"
 }`

When I try to download the webContentLink with the same Bearer token in the request headers, I am redirected to https://doc-0k-08-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/...

The Bearer token doesn't seem to work for this googleusercontent.com domain, and my server is eventually forwarded on to a sign in page (which is not good for a server app).

When trying to make this second request, I noticed the response headers contains:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,OPTIONS
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."`

I assume this last header is pointing me to the problem, and it has something to do with the redirect going to a different domain, but I'm not sure what I need to do about it.  I thought the access token granted through OAuth2 with the proper scope should allow me to do everything.  It does seem to work for everything else (accessing spreadsheets, documents, etc.), but I am having difficulty downloading images in this way.

Here is a detailed list of requests and responses:

1. Request: OAuth2 call to get access token with my client id and secret.
2. Response: Received the access token.  Good
3. Request: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=teamDrive&includeTeamDriveItems=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&teamDriveId=[myTeamDriveID]` with Authorization token in header.
4. Response.  Status 200.  Received file list.  Awesome.
5. For each image, request the webContentLink with the Authorization token in header
6. Request: `https://drive.google.com/a/[myTeamDriveDomain]/uc?id=[fileID]&export=download`
7. Response: Status 302 with P3P header `CP="This is not a P3P policy!` Redirected to `http://docs.google.com/a/[myTeamDriveDomain]/nonceSigner?nonce=[alphaNumericID]&continue=https://doc-0g-08-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/[longAlphaNumericID]/[longAlphaNumericID]/[longNumericID]/[longNumericID]/[longNumericID]/[longAlphaNumericID]?e%3Ddownload%26h%3D[longNumericID]&hash=[hashValue]`
8. Request: Get redirect url from previous response with Authorization token in header
9. Response: Status 302.  Redirected to `https://www.google.com/a/]myTeamDriveDomain]/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=[previousRedirectURL]&followup=[previousRedirectURL]`
10. Request: Get redirect url from previous response with Authorization token in header
11. Response: Status 200.  This is the login page.  While debugging, if I enter my credentials I will get the image, but the server can't do this.  It needs to be able to use Access tokens

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to download the file content to your app, you don't use webContentLink. Instead you simply `get` the file-id with `alt=media` (for binary files) or export to a particular format (for Google docs). See  `https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads`

Comment: Thank you!  That did the trick.  I guess I completely misunderstood how to do this.  For others reading this, I simply issued a GET to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[fileid]?supportsTeamDrives=true&alt=media` with my Authorization token in the header and it worked.